# reassign a file pointer in loop

Tags: c, file, freopen

I need to reassign a single file pointer to multiple files sequentially.

I have the file paths correctly in a string path.

when i pass the path and the file pointer to a function to reassign, I get "Aborted (core dumped)"..

```
FILE * fptr;        //Global file pointer
FILE * getfptrr(char * path)
{

    fclose(fptr);
    fptr = fopen(path, "r");

    if(fptr!=NULL)
        return fptr;
    else 
    {
        printf("\n Something's Wrong!!! \n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Should I use frepoen?? and how...

Or any other options??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not check that the `fptr` is not `NULL` before you call `fclose`.

Initialize `fptr` to `NULL` in the definition, and then check that it's not `NULL` before calling `fclose` (or `freopen` which is actually what you're doing here).

Comment: Indeed, unlike `free`, `fclose` doesn't accept null pointers (passing a null pointer to `fclose` is an undefined behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the close() function:

[1] As a way to initialize the file pointer?

[2] Or are you trying to close a previously opened file?

If so:

[1] You can initialize the pointer with the following:

```
    fptr = NULL;
    fptr = fopen(path, "r");
```

[2] I would suggest to call close() in the same function where fopen() is used

I recommend you use an error return code instead of exit() as it's a more graceful way to terminate your program. Error codes make it easier to debug and follow program logic than having exit() functions throughout your code.